# Getting DRAM_Reads and DRAM_Writes in command line mode of CUDA Profiler

Tags: cuda, profiler

I am trying to use the CUDA Profiler in command line; I am interested in DRAM_Reads and DRAM_Writes - and I am providing the following counters in my CUDA_PROFILE_LOG file:

```
fb_subp0_read_sectors
fb_subp0_write_sectors
fb0_subp0_read_sectors
fb0_subp0_write_sectors
fb1_subp0_read_sectors
fb1_subp0_write_sectors
```

But I notice in my cuda_profile files, there is an error like:

```
NV_Warning: Ignoring the invalid profiler config option: fb0_subp0_read_sectors
NV_Warning: Ignoring the invalid profiler config option: fb0_subp0_write_sectors
NV_Warning: Ignoring the invalid profiler config option: fb1_subp0_read_sectors
NV_Warning: Ignoring the invalid profiler config option: fb1_subp0_write_sectors
```

The values I get from fb_subp0_read_sectors and fb_subp0_write_sectors counters are not equal to what I get from NVidia Visual Profiler, which is perhaps because I am not passing correct counters to the config file. 
The GPU is Tesla M2050 and CUDA 4.1 is used. How do I get DRAM_Reads and DRAM_Writes in command line?

EDIT: After doing a bit of read-up, I think GPU could either have fb0/1... or fb... counters. But even if I have:

```
fb_subp0_read_sectors
fb_subp0_write_sectors
fb_subp1_read_sectors
fb_subp1_write_sectors
```

I get the warning:

```
NV_Warning: Counter 'fb_subp1_read_sectors' is not compatible with other selected counters and it cannot be profiled in this run.
NV_Warning: Counter 'fb_subp1_write_sectors' is not compatible with other selected counters and it cannot be profiled in this run.
```

Thanks,
Sayan

Comment: Did you get the expected number of dram accesses as the output from this counters? The reason I asked is, when I used this counters to get the number of read accesses, it returned me weird results. i.e I was expecting 1920 (32byte) accesses but it returned only 30 accesses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all counters can be profiled in a single run, due to hardware constraints.

According to the warning message, you may try profiling the first two counters in the first run, and then the last two in the second run.

Comment: The CUDA Visual Profiler automatically runs the application multiple times in order to collect all results. Take a look at the pop up message when profiling the app. If you specify a lot of counters it sometimes takes 20+ runs.